# ¿Query para comparar registro contra anterior SQL?

Tags: sql-server

Hola necesito comparar los registros de una columna en un sola tabla. Cabe mencionar que los registros no siguen un orden

```
Columna1 type int
123
1213
13313
12
12
1213
1213
```

Algo asi deberia ser la query:

```
select (case when Columna1 = Columna1(registro_siguiente) then '0' else '1' end) as Resultado from tablaDatos
```

Comment: Las bases de datos no manejan un concepto de registro anterior y registro siguiente, salvo que puedas especificar porque es anterior o siguiente.

Comment: Lei algo sobre LAG y OVER pero nose si pudiera servirme

Comment: Lag es no deterministica. O sea que PUEDE ser que cada vez que la ejecutes tire un resultado distinto. over podria ser para ordenar el resultado.. Tal vez podrias dar un contexto mejor de lo que necesitas?

Comment: Para ir a un campo es necesario la referencia de la clave y para hacer más o menos lo que pides las claves deberían ser minimamente enteros, autoincrementables, y sobre todo susesivos. Esto ayudaría a obtener un anterior y un siguiente.

Comment: Tal y como te han dicho, deberías dar más información sobre como identificar el orden de los registros. Incluir DDL de la tabla ayudaría y sobre todo... saber cual es el orden por el que quieres el cálculo. Hay varias formas de hacerlo pero sin esa información es difícil ayudar.

Comment: @VíctorHugoTirado las claves son enteros, pero no autoincrementables, ni susesivas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes usar la función LEAD así, ordenando por el Id

```
SELECT 
    T.Id,
    CASE 
        WHEN T.Columna1 = LEAD(T.Columna1, 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY T.Id) THEN '0'
        ELSE '1'
    END AS [Igual al Siguiente]
FROM DBO.MyTable AS T
```

Comment: LEAD es no deterministico. En este caso, ordenar por id lo haria deterministico, siempre y cuando existiria un id, cosa que se le pregunto a OP y no contesto.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta en esta parte  END AS [Igual al Siguiente] que deberia de poner, disculpa si mi pregunta es muy obvia.

Comment: El END es el que cierra el case y ` AS [Igual al Siguiente]` es para nombrar la columna resultante

Comment: Es justo los que necesitaba, gracias